# how to install libssh2 on Centos + pecl

Tags: ssh, centos, deployment, pecl

I use phing as a deployment tool on CentOS and I'd like to use the SshTask, which required libssh2 to be installed.

I tried "pecl install ssh2" but that asks me for a libssh2 prefix [/usr?]

I noticed that this means I need to install libssh2 first, but yum does not have that package.
So my question is: what is the best way to install libssh2 on Centos and then install the pecl extension?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

to install libssh2 on centos follow the next steps:

1. download libssh2 from the official website (look for in google - i don't have reputation and can't post but 1 link)
2. extract it somewhere, then open a terminal and go in the folder where you extracted it and type these commands

   ```
   ./configure

   make

   make install
   ```

ALSO

you can install the rpmforge repos from DAG from here:

http://dag.wieers.com/rpm/packages/rpmforge-release/

(check your version, if you're on i386 you'll probably have to get the "Red Hat EL 5 - i386" one)

then do a

```
yum install libssh2
```

Comment: thanks, perfect info. Now when I'm installing "pecl install ssh2" it asks "libssh2 prefix? [/usr]". Is that ok, or should it be "/usr/lib/libssh2.so.1"? 

[user@centos deployment]# rpm -ql libssh2
/usr/lib/libssh2.so.1

Comment: no matter what I type there, it says: configure: error: The required libssh2 library was not found.  You can obtain that package from http://sourceforge.net/projects/libssh2/
ERROR: `/tmp/pear/download/ssh2-0.11.0/configure --with-ssh2=/usr/lib/libssh2.so.1' failed

Comment: solved: it needed this: yum install libssh2-devel

Comment: except for new errors: 
running: make

/tmp/pear/download/ssh2-0.11.0/ssh2.c:1104: warning: passing argument 4 of 'add_assoc_stringl_ex' discards qualifiers from pointer target type
/tmp/pear/download/ssh2-0.11.0/ssh2.c:1105: warning: passing argument 4 of 'add_assoc_stringl_ex' discards qualifiers from pointer target type
make: *** [ssh2.lo] Error 1
ERROR: `make' failed

Answer (score 2):

You need **libssh2-devel** not just libssh2. Here's a little shorter version

```
yum install libssh2-devel
pecl install ssh2-0.12
```

Comment: `No package libssh2-devel available.` when trying to install libssh2-devel

Comment: @vladkras which version of CentOS/RHEL and which repositories do you have installed (EPEL? Remi? etc)?

Comment: I have CentOS 6 and remi repo, check [my answer](http://serverfault.com/a/748490/256144) for more info

Comment: If you have "remi" repository, it provides php-pecl-ssh2, no need to build anything.

Answer (score 0):

Effort to install `libssh2-devel` using `yum` failed with error `No package libssh2-devel available.` (remi repo)

I downloaded it from [PECL website](https://pecl.php.net/package/ssh2) and installed via

```
# pecl install -f packagename.tgz
```

All other packages and dependencies were downloaded from [rpmfind.net](https://www.rpmfind.net) and installed like this

```
# rpm -ivh packagename.rpm
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did.

```
wget https://libssh2.org/download/libssh2-1.7.0.tar.gz
tar zxvf libssh2-1.7.0.tar.gz
cd libssh2-1.7.0
./configure
make
sudo make install
sudo yum install libssh2 libssh2-devel
sudo pecl install ssh2-0.13
```